# What does Blue Elixir do?

Tags: bloodborne

I've found a few rare Blue Elixirs, but I'm wondering what they do before I go using them?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]
<sub>Image 1 - [The Forbidden Woods](http://bloodborne.wikia.com/wiki/Forbidden_Woods). The Blue Elixir is a important item to master this area.</sub>

The Blue Elixir is a rare consumable that makes you invisble for about 30 seconds. You will be visible and can be spotted by enemies while you're moving, but invisible when you stand still.

The elixir gets described as *"Liquid medicine that makes still bodies undetectable"*.
It's a rare Item that can be dropped by Blue Eyed Wolfes and Church Giants. According to [this Redditor](http://www.reddit.com/316wvk) the Item has a 1% drop rate when killing Blue Eyed Wolfes.

Your enemies can use Blue Elixir to hide from you.
A Boss-enemy can still spot you while you're influenced by the Elixir

The Item gets removed from your Inventory after single use like all consumables.

[image]
<sub>Image 2 - A Blue Elixir as shown in the Inventory</sub>

Comment: I'd recommend giving your answer here a once-over.  There seem to be a decent number of spelling mistakes and inconsistent spelling of terms.

Comment: I'm sorry. English sint' my mother tongue.  
It would really help me if you could point out what's wrong. Thanks

Comment: s'ok.  Just something to remember.  You've got two different spellings of Elixir going on; you should choose one and stick with it, and your plural of Wolfes should be wolves.  Same with the Werewolves.  Other than that, it's looking pretty good, grammar and spelling-wise.

Comment: oh thank you. I'm really glad that you like it. I'll put some more effort into the article to improve it further.

Answer (score 1):

Consuming one makes you invisible for approximately 15 seconds. Useful if you want to pop some enemies off.

They also work a treat on some boss levels, but when they're down to 33% health, be aware they'll still be able to spot you.

They're completely ineffective against some bosses.